# How can I keep the local copy of all my GitHub repositories updated?

Tags: git, git-pull

I have all the GitHub repositories that I work on in a local folder in my computer in this way:

```
all_repos/
├── repo_1
├── repo_2
├── repo_3
├── ...
├── repo_n
```

How can I keep them all updated with the version on GitHub automatically?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, I already solved the problem (see self answer), I wanted to post it here to help people with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved very simply with this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in *; do
    if [[ -d "$d/.git" ]]; then
        git -C "$d" fetch
    fi
done
```

Comment: Skip the pushd/popd sequence using `git -C "$d" fetch`.

Comment: Thanks @torek! I should have expected such an option to exist. I'll update my own scripts too, not just this answer.

Comment: But you know, if I think about it, I've used it before, it's just not in my habits.

Answer (score -1):

Just add this Python `pull_all.py` script to that folder:

```
all_repos/
├── pull_all.py
├── repo_1
├── repo_2
├── repo_3
├── ...
├── repo_n
```

And inside the script `pull_all.py`:

```
import os
import subprocess

folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
subfolders = [ f.path for f in os.scandir(folder) if f.is_dir() ]

for subfolder in subfolders:
    print(f"Updating {subfolder}")
    os.system(f"cd {subfolder}; git fetch")
```

Just run the script from inside the `all_repos` folder with:

```
python pull_all.py
```

to update all repositories.

Comment: What you want to do is fetch, not pull.

Comment: @matt Git Fetch is the command that tells the local repository that there are changes available in the remote repository without bringing the changes into the local repository. Git Pull on the other hand brings the copy of the remote directory changes into the local repository. Given that I want to apply the changes pull is better right?

Comment: No, fetch doesn't merely look; it actually fetches, syncing you with the remote. — Do you grasp the difference between your remote-tracking branches and your local branches? Fetch brings _all_ your remote-tracking branches up to date. Pull does that too, and then brings just _one_ local branch up to date by merging — which might fail or even error out, if a repo happens to have its head at a local branch with no upstream. You're not going bring _all_ your local branches up to date, so why bring _any_ up to date, especially if you could get an error in the middle of the operation.

Comment: Plus, pull will only affect the local branch that is checked out in the repo.... if there is more that one local branch that is a _copy_ of the remote branch, they won't be affected.